# AngularJS 1.5 calling a method from another in component's controller

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularJS 1.5 `component` in my application.  sample code of component's controller as bellow:

```
function testController()
{
    var vm = this;
    activate();   // this will be called on first load on component.

    vm.testMethod = function ()
    {
        return "test Method";
    }

   function activate()
   {
        console.log(vm.testMethod());
   }
```

when I execute this I am getting error

> TypeError: vm.testMethod is not a function.

I know I can create a local function to controller not appending **`vm.`**, however, in my need, I have a `vm.testMethod()` used in template to get return some text, which is working properly. e.g.

**`--template code`**

```
{{$ctrl.testMethod()}} // This works properly and display 'test Method' on page.
```

Due to some reason, I am trying to call `vm.testMethod()` inside another method e.g. `activate()`, however getting an error mentioned above?

May I know if am missing anything or trying something which is not possible.

Comment: Where does you call the `activate()` function?

Comment: Code updated. So basically it will be called on component-controller load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues does not have anything to do with Angular :-)

Your `activate` function is hoisted because it is a function *declaration*. That why you can call it "before your wrote it". BUT, `vm.testMethod` is a function *expression* and won't get hoisted.

Here is a super simple example that shows the issue your having:

```js
var vm = {};

console.log(vm.hello);
vm.hello = function () {};
console.log(vm.hello);
```

I would recommend you to read [this article](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/) for a better understanding of how expressions and declarations work in JavaScript. Also, in order to prevent this from happening again you should follow [this advice from John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#style-y033):

*Always write function declarations at the bottom of your controller and assign them at the top when you defined your `vm` variable.*

Comment: actually I tried this option before asking question. I tried by shuffling positions of  these functions, however error remains as is.

Comment: Not all I guess :P If you move your `activate()` below the `vm.testMethod` assignment it works, see https://jsbin.com/bacido/edit?js,console

Comment: please provide valid link, I don't see any relevant code there.

Comment: Sorry, here you go: jsbin.com/yawuje/edit?js,console Please re-read my andere. If you follow it this will solve your issue.